# How to convert random integers into float between 0 and 1

Tags: javascript, math, random

I am using data from [this site](https://qrng.anu.edu.au/random-binary/) to get random numbers. They come in as a buffer, which I convert to binary, then into integer. I would like to finally convert those random numbers into decimal values between 0 and 1 like `Math.random()` produces.

For example, if I have the integer `151`, what do I need to do to make it look more like this float `0.0151234252525372`.

Here is my code:

```
    const bent = require('bent')
    const getBuffer = bent('buffer')

    let array = []
    async function random(){
        try{
            let result = await getBuffer("https://qrng.anu.edu.au/wp-content/plugins/colours-plugin/get_one_binary.php")
            let integer = parseInt(result.toString('utf8'), 2)
            let float = parseFloat(integer) // convert to a decimal between 0 and 1 like Math.random() produces
            array.push(float)
        }
        catch (error){return console.log(error)}
    }
    
    setInterval(()=>random().then(result => {
        console.log(array)
    }),50)
```

I'm not opposed to using the result of `Math.random()` to apply some math to the initial random number, but I'm just not sure what the right math would be.

Comment: Assuming the data you have is really binary, you should not convert it to string, but rather use the methods of ArrayBuffer and TypedArray for getting integers, bytes, etc. directly.  Also, I find it unusual to have to convert random bits to floating-point numbers if the numbers will be used for information security purposes.

Comment: Thank you - I will look into ArrayBuffer and TypedArray. This isn't for information security purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide that random by max value - and max value for such generated bit sequence is `2^length(sequence)` (^ her denotes power, `**`, `Math.pow`).

For example, if current buffer is "01000100", you need to calculate

```
68/2^8 = 68/256 = 0.265625
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The number always needs to be between 0 and 1 for my purposes. Here's an example output: `buffer=<Buffer 31 31 31 31 31 30 30 30>`, `binary=11111000`, `integer=248`, result: `float=24.8`, where I am using `let float = integer/2^8`

Comment: `2^8` means 2 raised to the power of 8; unfortunately javascript interprets `^` as bitwise exclusive or.  you want to use `2**8` instead which is the appropriate operator (in modern browsers) or you could be more explicit and use `Math.pow`

Comment: @SamMason Ah nice catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using math rather than programming as what @Mbo suggested. I haven't ran the code but fairly certain it will execute. More or less take the ((log of x)/x) and I did that on your float var.

```
const bent = require('bent')
    const getBuffer = bent('buffer')
    
    let array = []
    async function random(){
        try{
            let result = await getBuffer("https://qrng.anu.edu.au/wp-content/plugins/colours-plugin/get_one_binary.php")
            let integer = parseInt(result.toString('utf8'), 2)
            let float = (Math.log(integer)/integer) // convert to a decimal between 0 and 1 like Math.random() produces
            array.push(float)
        }
        catch (error){return console.log(error)}
    }
    
    setInterval(()=>random().then(result => {
        console.log(array)
    }),50)
```