# How can I convert BigInt to float in js?

Tags: javascript, biginteger

Lets say I have a BigInt(66555444333222111) and I want to convert it to float loke the output will be 6.6555444E9.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293230/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-a-float-in-javascript

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a float, or do you want to format it as scientific notation? For example, should `2n**2000n` be Infinity or 1.1481306E602?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970656/11954917

Comment: Do you know the max int value? I asked a similar question a few days ago and have the math to convert it to float based on the number of bits. I later used the math in the accepted answer to convert a Uint32array to float: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470083/how-to-convert-random-integers-into-float-between-0-and-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

```
console.log( Number( BigInt('66555444333222111') ).toExponential() )
```